# Do the properties of electrons change or are they "fundemental" and unchanging?

Tags: fundamental-entities, quantum

This question was closed on physics exchange.  Can anyone help me with this question here?   As I understand it, everything evolves, which means that everything changes based on causes and conditions.  So to the contrary, are fundamental particals and the "quantum" of Quantum mechanics constant, unchanging and have always existed?

Comment: Why was it closed on physics exchange, what part was away from physics?

Comment: Quantum particles move around, their wave functions evolve and some of their internal parameters can change (spin direction). They can even be [created or annihilated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation) in collisions. They also have internal parameters that never change (mass and charges).

Comment: Particles are understood to be quanta of quantum field theories. But quantum field theories, especially those of electrons, are thought to be so-called "effective theories," i.e. they make good predictions away from singularities due to high/low energy, but may have little to do with what actually *is*. The principled physicist can usually only speak to what mathematical formalism makes good predictions and must remain agnostic about (or at least aloof about) the metaphysics of his formalism.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins, sure but here in philosophy se we are interested in the ontological part too.

Comment: @IoannisPaizis As you should be. My point was just that one shouldn't make the mistake of thinking that the standard model speaks to ontology. The consensus, I'm fairly sure, is that the standard model is an effective theory. To be clear, this is not always the consensus in physics. For example, the theory that electricity is the flow of electrons was not, in its time, considered an effective theory. It was thought that there really were these discrete entities called electrons that transported something called electric charge.

Comment: Field theory is a correction to that theory, but it turns out that it is (as in evidence points to this fact) *only* an effective theory. Maybe it's clearer to say that there are theories we *know* to be only effective, theories we suspect are only effective, and theories that we think actually speak to ontology. The standard model is somewhere in the middle of this spectrum. If it would be helpful, I could give examples of physical theories that lie on different points of this spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose someone will write an explanatory answer in the context of quantum mechanics. Just a quote from *Heisenberg*.

> The atoms or elementary particles themselves are not as real; they form a
> world of potentialities or possibilities rather than one of things or
> facts.

*Heisenberg Physics and Philosophy p186.*

Comment: I am onterested  to know where Heisenberg makes this statement, in which context? Do you know?

Comment: Don't know, I had found it in a book I think of Rupert Sheldrake, and now I googled it. Besides the quote, I think that the link is sufficient : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation#:~:text=In%20quantum%20physics%2C%20a%20quantum,Werner%20Heisenberg's%20uncertainty%20principle.

Comment: The linked article "Quantum fluctuations" speaks about "virtual particles". In general, electrons with their huge lifetime are not virtual particles. - It would be helpful to know the context of Heisenberg's original statement.

Comment: @Jo Wehler, not exactly that, but I found this ITS AWESOME, LISTEN ALL : https://youtu.be/xbpOMkBMtYU?si=mRu_b7DLrTeUpbCL

Comment: Thanks for this great historical document. Do you understand acustically Heisenberg's expression at 6:13? - But the clip does not relate to the quoted statement above.

Comment: @Jo Wehler, NO I think it's German. Anyway if I find I will notify.

Comment: Sorry, the problematic word in Heisenberg's clip is at 6:31.

Comment: @Jo Wehler, I don't get the word either, but I think that he emphasizes what he said before that language is not enough to describe the ontological implications of QM, so it's left to philosophers to complete the job.

Comment: @Jo Wehler, I found it. Heisenberg Physics and Philosophy (his own book) p186. (archive.org) pdf.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the quote refers to the end of his chapter 10 on "Language and Reality in Modern Physics". - Indeed, Heisenberg discriminates between, on one hand, the reality of the phenomena observed in experiments with elementary particles. And on the other hand, the world of tendencies and possibilities which characterizes the ontology of elementary particles.

Answer (score 2):

They are fundamental and their inherent properties are unchanging as far as we know. Current estimates suggest the lifetime of an electron is vastly longer than the age of the Universe. Of course, they also have variable properties such as position, energy, etc, which change according to circumstances, and they can be created or annihilated.

Comment: aren't elementary particles quantum fluctuation in vacuum?

Comment: and, how can something be eternal if it's properties change? sounds like a theological perspective to me.

Comment: Is this is the explanatory gap between QM and physics? that is bridged by Platonism?

Comment: @IoannisPaizis Stable particles like electrons are not quantum fluctuations. - The old substance-attribute theory of Aristotle attempts to explain why the substance remains the same, but the attributes change. - As a first guess one may compare an electron to a substance. But a closer look from the viewpoint of quantum field theory refutes that assumption that electrons have an identity as individual particles, i.e. that they exemplify the concept of a substance. Quite unusal and takes some getting used to!

Comment: @Jo Wehler, so you say that what physics considers a stable particle, in QM has no identity, is not an individual particle: that's what I am saying.

Comment: @Jo Wehler, my comment about Platonism is that physics uses Platonism in the sense that they define a particle as stable ie as existing always, although it's not, it's a process.

Comment: @Ioannis Paizis What about converting your two last comments into a separate question? Then there would be more space to discuss how quantum mechanics (QM) and quantum field theory (QFT) as its extension are questioning our usual concepts and also the applicability of technical terms from Plato or Aristotle or any other philosophy. - Like you I consider the switch from a substance view to a process view to be helpful, possibly even necessary.

Comment: @Jo Wehler, Just for reference, in Greek most words include the concept of process, for example: entelechy = "εντελέχεια" = ἐν + τέλος + ἔχω = inside + final + has, and is also female which denotes a "becoming of", so the Greek translation (shortened and quick) = the physical process by which unmorphed matter is transformed from the field of potentiality to the field of physical reality by completing its teleological self realization : https://el.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1