# How do Leibniz' possible-worlds model and Heisenberg's view of microphysics relate to each other?

Tags: possible-worlds, quantum-interpretations, leibniz

In his answer to a [former question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105154/do-the-properties-of-electrons-change-or-are-they-fundemental-and-unchanging) @IoannisPaizis presents a quote of Heisenberg from his book [Physics and Philosophy](https://www.amazon.de/Physics-Philosophy-Classics-Heisenberg-2000-08-03/dp/B0161TD1KY/ref=sr_1_2?Adv-Srch-Books-Submit.x=63&Adv-Srch-Books-Submit.y=5&__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85Z%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1700244675&refinements=p_27%3AHeisenberg%2Cp_28%3APhysics%20and%20Philosophy&s=books&sr=1-2&unfiltered=1)

> The atoms or elementary particles themselves are not as real; they
> form a world of potentialities or possibilities rather than one of
> things or facts.

The context of the quote makes it clear, that Heisenberg discriminates between

- on one hand, the one **reality** when we force the microworld  by an experiment to create
  a phenomenon,
- and on the other hand, the world of undisturbed elementary particles,
  which is a collection of **possible worlds** according to the tendencies
  and possibilities described by quantum mechanics.

This view prompts the questions: Is the latter world, i.e. microphysics when it is not observed or - stronger - when it is not prepared by experiments, an example of possible worlds in the sense of Leibniz?

Corollary: The concept of a necessary event is a concept which gets its meaning from framing the event by Leibniz’ possible-worlds model. An event is necessary if it happens in all possible worlds.

Comment: Heisenbertg's conception is closer to Aristotle's potentiality and Deleuze's virtual than to Leibniz's flashed out possible worlds, see [How does the concept of the 'virtual' (Deleuze) relate to 'counterfactuals' (Lewis)?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/51901/9148) Quantum superpositions before decoherence lack the definitiveness of possible world descriptions, possible worlds are more like fully decohered branches without collapse as in MWI.